# Query String to Control BXSlider startSlide

Tags: jquery, string, bxslider

I am trying to have the start slide on bxslider controlled by a query string.  For example, the url http://page.html?id=3 would start slide three and the user could then advance the slides in an infinite loop.  The code I currently have is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  startSlide: 0,
  infiniteLoop: true,
  });
});
```

I am not sure how to pull the query string value and then insert its value into the startSlide.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can either manually extract id from `window.location.search`. Or use some library with `deparam` function in it.

```
$(function(){
var search = window.location.search.substr(1),
    params = $.map(search.split('&'), function(item) {
         var matches = item.split('=');
         return { name: matches[0], value: matches[2]};
    }),
    id = parseInt($.grep(params, function(param){
        return param.name === 'id';
    }).value, 10);

$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  startSlide: id - 1, //zero based
  infiniteLoop: true,
  });
})
```