# Reinitialize bxSlider from a new slide after page reload

Tags: jquery, magento-1.9, bxslider

Hello everyone,

I am showing Magento products in bxSlider. When user clicks on any slide i.e. Magento product from a bxSlider, then user redirects to that product page.

**Here basically, after page reloads, I want to start a bxSlider slide show from a currently clicked slide.(Slider should point to currently selected slide)**

I have tried following code. But it is not working properly. Sometimes, bxSlider's next and prev buttons are not responding if I specify 'startSlide' value as emq_slide_index!!!

Can anyone help me? Your help will be highly appreciated.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $t = jQuery.noConflict();
    var emq_slide_index;
    $t(document).ready(function() 
    {
        var slider = $t('.bxslider').bxSlider({
                /* startSlide: " value to start from slide "*/
                slideWidth: 200,
                slideMargin: 12,
                minSlides: 1,
                maxSlides: 2

            });     
            //slider.goToSlide(emq_slide_index);
        $t('.prod_slide').on('click',function(e)
        {
            emq_slide_index = ($t(this).index());
            slider.reloadSlider({
                slideWidth: 200,
                slideMargin: 12,
                minSlides: 1,
                maxSlides: 2,
            });
            //console.log(emq_slide_index);
            //slider.goToSlide(emq_slide_index);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the option `.getCurrentSlide()` and `.destroySlider()` like this:

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        slideWidth: 666,
        slideMargin: 12,
        minSlides: 1,
        maxSlides: 2,
        moveSlides: 1
      });

      $('.prod_slide').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var emq_slide_index = slider.getCurrentSlide();
        slider.destroySlider({});
        slider.reloadSlider({
          slideWidth: 333,
          slideMargin: 12,
          minSlides: 1,
          maxSlides: 2,
          moveSlides: 1,
          startSlide: emq_slide_index
        });
      });
    });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>bxReload</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="bxslider">
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/666x375/000/fff.png&text=FIRST" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/666x375/cab/00c.png&text=SECOND" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/666x375/666/f4f.png&text=THIRD" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/666x375/9a7/941.png&text=FOURTH" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/666x375/fff/000.png&text=LAST" />
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button><a class="prod_slide" href="#">Reload</a>
  </button>
  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

I made the reload half the size so it's obvious that it's not the original bxSlider, you can adjust accordingly. I find that in order to reload bxSlider, you get better results destroying it and then reloading. During reload, the option for `startSlide` should have the value that was stored in `var = emq_slide_index` before the original bxSlider's destruction.

## UPDATE: http://arcx.s3.amazonaws.com/bx1/1.html

This update uses a URL hash to locate the `startSlide` of the next page. bxSlider is a cold mistress, if ye not careful she'll freeze up inexplicably. Since there's `maxSlides: 2`, always use even numbers of slides. There's some quirkiness when you got to the last slide, so I set the limit to 0 to 5 for loading, but you can still loop through 0 to 5 to 0 manually.

This helped: [Query String to Control BXSlider startSlide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13444854/query-string-to-control-bxslider-startslide)

### Page 1

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
      var opts = {
        slideWidth: 666,
        slideMargin: 12,
        minSlides: 1,
        maxSlides: 2,
        moveSlides: 1
      }
      var bx = $(".bxslider").bxSlider(opts);
      document.getElementById('send').addEventListener('click',
        function (event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          var maxSlides = parseInt(bx.getSlideCount(), 10);
          var id = parseInt(bx.getCurrentSlide(), 10) + 1;
          if(id > maxSlides.length - 1) {
            id = maxSlides.length - 1;
          }
          else if(id < 0) {
            id = 0;
          }
          else {
            id = id;
          }
          window.location = '2.html#' + id;
        }, false);
    });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>bxReload Page 1</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.css"
  rel="stylesheet"> </head>

<body>
  <ul class="bxslider">
    <li> <img id="0" src="http://placehold.it/666x375/000/fff.png&text=FIRST"
      height="375" width="666" /> </li>
    <li> <img id="1" src="http://placehold.it/666x375/cab/00c.png&text=SECOND"
      height="375" width="666" /> </li>
    <li> <img id="2" src="http://placehold.it/666x375/666/f4f.png&text=THIRD"
      height="375" width="666" /> </li>
    <li> <img id="3" src="http://placehold.it/666x375/9a7/941.png&text=FOURTH"
      height="375" width="666" /> </li>
    <li> <img id="4" src="http://placehold.it/666x375/0a0/f91.png&text=FIFTH"
      height="375" width="666" /> </li>
    <li> <img id="5" src="http://placehold.it/666x375/fff/000.png&text=LAST"
      height="375" width="666" /> </li>
  </ul>
  <input type="hidden" id="idx" /> <a id="send" href="#">Next</a>
  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

### Page 2

```js
    $(function () {
      var search = window.location.search.substr(1),
        params = $.map(search.split('&'), function (item) {
          var matches = item.split('=');
          return {
            name: matches[0],
            value: matches[2]
          };
        }),
        id = parseInt($.grep(params, function (param) {
          return param.name === 'id';
        }).value, 10);
      var opts = {
        slideWidth: 666,
        slideMargin: 12,
        minSlides: 1,
        maxSlides: 2,
        moveSlides: 1
      }
      var bx = $('.bxslider').bxSlider(opts);
      bx.goToSlide(id);
    });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>bxReload Page 2</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.css"
  rel="stylesheet"> </head>

<body>
  <ul class="bxslider">
    <li> <img id="0" src="http://placehold.it/666x375/000/fff.png&text=FIRST"
      height="375" width="666" /> </li>
    <li> <img id="1" src="http://placehold.it/666x375/cab/00c.png&text=SECOND"
      height="375" width="666" /> </li>
    <li> <img id="2" src="http://placehold.it/666x375/666/f4f.png&text=THIRD"
      height="375" width="666" /> </li>
    <li> <img id="3" src="http://placehold.it/666x375/9a7/941.png&text=FOURTH"
      height="375" width="666" /> </li>
    <li> <img id="4" src="http://placehold.it/666x375/0a0/f91.png&text=FIFTH"
      height="375" width="666" /> </li>
    <li> <img id="5" src="http://placehold.it/666x375/fff/000.png&text=LAST"
      height="375" width="666" /> </li>
  </ul>
  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
  
  </body>
  
  </html>
```

Comment: Hello @zerOOne .. Thank  you  for your answer. But you have mentioned "event.preventDefault();". Which is preventing a page from reloading.**My page should be redirected to a new page and then slider should point to the selected image.**

Comment: Try placing the url in the href and remove the event.preventDefault();. You might have to use Ajax, I'm not familiar with cookie cutter sites.

Comment: Sorry but I can not use ajax for this. New page should be loaded. So here main problem is to point the selected slide after page load.

Comment: Carry over the emq_slide_index in a hash, then apply it to new bxslider's startSlide. Since it's a new page just make bxSlider as normal, no reload should be necessary.

Comment: What is required? Because I just finished the update. It takes the current index number of page one and then applies it to the next page's bxSlider's startSlide. If that's not the functionality you required, then what is it?

Comment: Exactly that is needed. Have you made changes to your answer?? I f not can you do it??

Comment: I'm going to use a real webspace because this demo involves 2 pages. Standby.

Comment: @ved sorry, I fell asleep :\ The url is posted in my answer.

Comment: Hello @zerOOne .. thank you for your answer.. but I have also faced the same issue.. can you check in your link.. when page reloads then next and prev buttons doesn't work.. that is the problem.

Comment: @ved Aaargh! bxSlider is insidious -_- Sorry ved, you have found an issue that I cannot resolve. Do you have access to server side scripting like PHP? If so, that will be your solution. If not, then you can pull a request at https://github.com/stevenwanderski/bxslider-4, edit the question to include a PHP tag, or wait for a better answer. Sorry, I can't help you any further, PHP is beyond my capabilities atm.

Comment: @zerOOne.. it's okk.. u really helped me.. really thank you for your help.. :)